# How to replace text from divs with only unique values from a specific index of multiple nested arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm working on a function that loops over an array (with arrays) and then replaces the text on a few divs with the value of index 1 of the nested arrays.

But only with these conditions:

- the nested array needs to have a specific (string) value on index 0 (which is 'categorie 1')
- it should only give the value of index 1 of the nested array **if the value of index 1 is a unique value** (I mean, if there are other nested arrays with the same value inside index 1, it is not unique. I do not mean unique inside the nested array itself).

The function get's activated by an event handler (clicking on 'Categorie 1', see codepen).
When clicking on categorie 1, the following values: **themaA1 themaA2 themaA3 themaA4 themaA5 themaA6** (each value in a different div) should be visible inside the divs of the green container (see codepen).

Unfortunately I'm not able to get it work.

What does work is looping and putting data in the different divs which shares the same value on index 0. See code below.

```
function displayThemes() {
  let theme = "i";
  for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    theme = forms[i][1];

    if (forms[i][0] === "Categorie 1")
      document.getElementById("theme" + i).innerHTML = theme;
  }
}
```

What does not work is getting the right data in the divs (only the unique values).

I got this far (see code below) but it does not work unfortunately.

```
  function displayThemes() {
  let theme = "i";
  for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    theme = forms[i][1];

    if (forms[i][0] === "Categorie 1" && forms[i][1] !== theme)
      document.getElementById("theme" + i).innerHTML = theme;
  }
}
```

Here is the full code with interface: https://codepen.io/cheizer66/pen/pobXBmy

I'm not sure why it does not work. What am I doing wrong? What should you do differently? What could make it work?
I hope I stated the problem clear enough and looking forward to your respons!

Best regards,

OK

ps: Yes, I'm new to javascript and programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had two problems.

**first:** you assigned `forms[i][1]` to `theme` variable. and then in the second condition in the `if` statment, you checked if it's **not** equal to `theme`, which of course is false. so the code never entered the `if` block.
i solved it by assigning it with the previous forms element (or 'check' if the previous element doesn't exist).

**second:** when you try to catch the element with ID 'theme1' with the `("theme" + i)` expression, `i` value is actualy 11 and not 1, because the `if` blocked the previous 10 elements with the identical value of index one. so it couldn't find an HTML element with ID `theme11`.
i solved it by adding a `counter` variable which the code increases by one every time it enter's the `if` block;

```
let counter = -1;
function displayThemes() {
  for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    let theme = i === 0 ? 'check' : forms[i - 1][1];

    if (forms[i][0] === "Categorie 1" && forms[i][1] !== theme) {
      counter++;
      document.getElementById("theme" + counter).innerHTML = forms[i][1];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I now have it (partly) fixed, see this GitHub: https://github.com/okestens/vertical-filter.git   The filtered arrays are spread on the right divs. Now I was wondering. If I want to be the divs 'empty' again. what would be the best way to do this? For example and get it clear, see this image: https://ibb.co/VNkr9B4

Comment: can't you create a function which iterates over the relevent elements and empties them?

Comment: Yes, You're absolutely right. I've got it working now. Thanks!